# Can create a file but not write

Tags: file

I have an application that writes to a log file and also creates other files as it runs. What I am seeing happening is that, in some rare cases, the application is running fine (creating and writing files and appending to the log file) and then suddenly the application can continue to create and delete files, but the application cannot write to a file. The log file stops writing in the middle of a line and other files that are created are 0 bytes because although they can be created, we could not write to them.

Rebooting the machine helps and we can create and write files with no issue after the reboot. All affected machines are running either RHEL6 or CentOS 6. This is not a drive space issue, there is tons of room left on the machines that display the issue.

Does anyone have any clue what might cause this behavior?

Comment: Maybe there is a concurrent access to the file? Is the file also used by other processes?

Comment: That may be the issue for one of the files, but not for all of them and certainly not for the log file since there is only one process that writes to that file.